# remove rightmost `.` and number from a character vector in R

Tags: r, regex, string, character

I was wondering how I could remove only the **rightmost** `.` and **number** that appears in the elements of vector `nm` in my R code below?

```
nm <- c("Bit.KnoA.SHORT.1", "Bit.KnoA.SHORT..2.2", "Bit.KnoA.SHORT.3", "Bit.KnoA.DEL1.1", 
        "Bit.KnoA.DEL1..4.1")
```

Comment: Only the very last "." and number? Could you show the result you want? `gsub("\\.[0-9]$", "", nm)` or `str_remove(nm, "\\.[0-9]$")` using `stringr` should work, depending.

Comment: @paqmo, your first solution worked thanks!